# navigate to specific fragment with notifications

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using cloud functions whit firebase to send notification to my android device. The notification is working great, but I need to navigate to specific fragments depending on the notification, but first of all, I need to go to LoginActivity to sign in the user.

This is my payload

```
const payload = {
            data: {
                title: "Some title",
                body: "some body message",
                click_action: "to_profile"
            },              
        }
```

And this is MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
val intent = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)


        override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    
            if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
                sendNotification(remoteMessage)
            }
    }
    
        fun sendNotification(message: RemoteMessage){
    
            createNotificationChannel()
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.isologo)
                .setContentTitle(message.data["title"])
                .setContentText(message.data["body"])
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
    
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
        }
```

The navigation to LoginActivity works great, and goes directly to the main activity which contain a lot of fragments (because is the flow of the app).

I need to go to specific fragment of main activity depending on the click__action parameter of notification data.

Thanks!